# Виды кавычек: «елочки» и “лапки”

Tags: кавычки

Иногда в тексте встречаются кавычки в виде елочек — «елочки», а иногда — в виде лапок — “лапки”. Чем они отличаются и какие из них предпочтительнее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе, между этими кавычками нет разницы. Однако существует понятие "полиграфических" кавычек. То есть в печатном тексте (в газете, журнале или книге) кавычки всегда должны иметь вид скобок: «». Для того чтобы набрать их на клавиатуре компьютера, нужно либо выбрать их из таблицы символов, либо набрать код: Alt+0171 — « и Alt+0187 — ».

Answer (score 1):

„Лапки“ вот такие должны быть, а не как в вопросе.

В принципе, допускаются оба варианта: и «ёлочки», и „лапки“. Но мне привычнее «ёлочки» — вероятно, потому, что в советских послевоенных книгах они преобладают. И там прослеживается такая традиция: «вложенные кавычки делать „лапками“». Если же „лапки“ недоступны, допускаются и «ёлочки», но тогда на стыке «вложенных «кавычек» принято отказываться от дублирования знака.

Answer (score -2):

Вижу разницу в том, что:
«ёлочки» надо использовать при показателе прямой речи, а также при выдержке (цитате) из другого текста;
"лапки" же надо использовать при названиях, а также при слове (словосочетании), которое в тексте как бы обретает название и звучит вместо длинного определения;
есть ещё одиночные кавычки - ', они должны использоваться при переносном смысле.